# Vaadin ComboBox fix unnatural scrolling

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

It appears when you attempt to scroll within a ComboBox, the listing moves a page at a time instead of smoothly scrolling up or down one line at a time, I'd prefer it scroll smoothly one line at a time instead of paging.  This possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with this version of component. But ComboBox have filtering functionality which is useful when you have a lot items in a list.

Probably, solution is to create your own widget.